# How to rotate map markers with Skobbler

Tags: skmaps

Is there a way to rotate individual map marker with Skobbler in the iOS and Android SDK by specifying the degree?

For example, in google Map I can use: CLLocation Class london.rotation = degrees to specify the direction this map marker should point to in MapView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point the SDK does not support this functionality.